# Sanhedrin 6:6 - Halacha or common practice?

Tags: mishna, capital-punishment, maseches-sanhedrin

The Mishna in [Sanhedrin 6:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.6.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) speaks about after a Sanhedrin kills a someone who is liable the death penalty:

> והקרובים באים ושואלין בשלום הדיינים. ובשלום העדים. כלומר שאין בלבנו עליכם כלום. שדין אמת דנתם.‏
>
> *The relatives (of the deceased) would come and ask about the well-being of the Judges and the well-being of the the witnesses, meaning (the witnesses are saying) "that there is nothing in our hearts against you, for you delivered true judgement"*

Is this statement of the Mishna a requirement for the family to abide to? Or was that the practice of the time?